# JSON variable containing an object?

Tags: json

Is it possible to have a `JSON` variable contain another `JSON` object?

For example:

```
{
   "myvariable" : {  "anothervariable" : 2 }
}
```

Comment: yes.Why do you think no?

Comment: the C#  `Type` should look like:`public class Myvariable
{
    public int anothervariable { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Myvariable myvariable { get; set; }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: YES!

Long answer: YEEEEEEEEEEES!

---

1. Are you on Chrome? If not, open this page using Chrome
2. Right-click anywhere on the page and select `Inspect Element`
3. Select `Console` tab
4. Type `var a = '{ "myvariable" : {  "anothervariable" : 2 }}';` to create a JSON string.
5. Type `var b = JSON.parse(a);` to parse your JSON into a Javascript object.
6. Now, you can access any of the references of your object

   ```
   > b
   ```

   > Object {myvariable: Object}

   ```
   > b.myvariable
   ```

   > Object {anothervariable: 2}

   ```
   > b.myvariable.anothervariable
   ```

   > 2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why shouldn't it be possible? That's the whole idea - see http://json.org/

Comment: I am trying and keep getting malformed JSON errors.

Comment: @Deekor What is the malformed JSON error that you get?